# nextint Preventing a nextLine from executing

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a method for adding an episode/multiple episodes, which uses `sc.nextInt` for validation, then `sc.nextLine` for the input of the name of the `episode(s)`.

However, the `sc.nextInt` prevents the `sc.nextLine` from executing. I have tried parsing the integer from a string, but this leads to an input mismatch. Placing an `sc.nextLine` between the two also does not work. Any tips?

```
public void addepisodes(Scanner sc) {

int arraylistlength;

System.out.println("How many Episodes are in this Series?");

boolean valid=false;

    do{

    if(sc.hasNextInt()){

        valid=true;

        arraylistlength = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Please enter List of Episodes");
        for (int i = 0; i < arraylistlength; i++) {
            System.out.println("Episode " + (i + 1));
            String nextEp = sc.nextLine();
            list_of_episodes.add(nextEp);

                              }
                       }
    else{
        System.out.println("Error, input an integer");
        sc.next();
        }
    }while(!valid);
                 }
```

Comment: I can't find any `sc.nextInt() ` in your code